# Redirect https to http (download file)

Tags: file, redirect, https

On the SERVER.COM server I have a file "ABC.XML", this file is available through the address with encryption: https://SERVER.COM/ABC.XML

How to redirect on my own appache server (MY-SERVER.COM) so that the file is available in the protocol without encryption: http://MY-SERVER.COM/ABC.XML ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html)

Comment: I expect an answer that he can copy (ctrl-c and ctrl-v) :D

Comment: I meant a ready-made solution, not a link to the documentation.